# Prism Event Aggregator - method cannot be read

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, eventaggregator

I've been doing a Wpf program for some time now. But when i create a application  and create multiple viewmodel. And i need to access a property in a different view model.

So in order to access it. I need each viewmodel to be static.

Then i searched how does view model should be communicating to each other.

Then i found an answer here

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892731/wpf-mvvm-how-do-viewmodels-communicate-with-each-other
```

So i searched for prism aggregator and i found a tutorial

```
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5ffb84/prism-event-aggregator-in-wpf-with-mvvm/
```

Then i followed it.

just like the tutorial. I added a `event class` in the Model folder

And here is the code

```
namespace MdbMerge.Model
{
   public sealed class Event
    {
        #region Class Properties

        internal static Event EventInstance
        {
            get
            {
                return eventInstance;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Instance Properties

        internal IEventAggregator EventAggregator
        {
            get
            {
                if (eventAggregator == null)
                {
                    eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
                }

                return eventAggregator;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        private Event()
        {

        }

        #endregion

        #region Class Fields

        private static readonly Event eventInstance = new Event();

        #endregion

        #region Instance Fields

        private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

        #endregion

    }
}
```

but when i set the datacontext of my viewmodel it gives me error

```
DataContext = new MdbMergeViewModel(MdbMerge.Model.Event.EventInstance.EventAggregator);
```

It says. `MdbMerge does not contain a definition for model.`

So how can i solve this?

Why does the Methods inside is not read?

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the structure of my program

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: `i need to access a property in a different view model` - then you're doing it the wrong way. View models provide data to views not other view models.

Comment: @Haukinger i need to access a property. in order for this view model to know if it a command can be executed. Am i doing it wrong? thank you

Comment: As @Haukinger said, this doesn't seem the correct way to go. A ViewModel should only present data from a Model to the View. If the ViewModel requires additional information then it should probably have a reference to the Model where that information is stored.

ViewModels should not be static either.

I think the issue you are experiencing though is you have a Namespace and Class clash(s) (Model and MdbMerge) - (Edit multiple clashes)

Comment: Can you please link me to a good mvvm tutorial? Thank you. So meaning i've been doing it the wrong way